# MySQL two fields in one table to SELECT two result rows from additional tables?

Tags: mysql

I have a table that contains two ids. I'd like to select the two id's from the first table and get a result set of two rows from two additional tables. Maybe I'm missing the obvious here, how do I grab multiple rows when I'm starting with two id's?

```
Table 1 = Intial SELECT
id | document1_id | document2_id

SELECT FROM table1 document_id1, document_id2

Table 2
document_id | document_title | document_description

Table 3
document_id | document_filename
```

I would like to get the two result rows that match document_id1 and document_id2. This is where I started to nest selects. This hasn't been working. I could do two JOINS here?

The result set that I'm looking to achieve is:

```
1 row from table 1
table1_id, document1_id, document2_id

2 rows from table 2
document_title, document_description that matches document1_id AND
document_title, document_description that matches document2_id

2 rows from table 3
document_filename that matches document1_id AND
document_filename that matches document2_id
```

I've shortened the number of actual columns in the tables to simply illustrate what I'm hoping to accomplish. To begin with, does this look like a good setup for the data? If yes, is there a simple method to select the data? Currently, I have a bunch of nested selects which is getting out of control and seems to be counter-productive. Anyways, as always any help or guidance is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answers above didn't quite give me the results I was looking to achieve. Ultimately this is what I ended up with that worked. Thanks for the help.

```
SELECT 
  t1.document1_id, t1.document2_id, 
  t21.document_title as t21_title, t21.document_description as t21_description, 
  t22.document_title as t22_title, t22.document_description as t22_description, 
  t31.document_filename as t31_filename, 
  t32.document_filename as t32_filename 
FROM 
  Table1 t1 
    INNER JOIN Table2 t21 
      ON t21.document_id = t1.document1_id 
    INNER JOIN Table2 t22 
      ON t22.document_id = t1.document2_id 
    INNER JOIN Table3 t31 
      ON t31.document_id = t1.document1_id 
    INNER JOIN Table3 t32 
      ON t32.document_id = t1.document2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it would be better to use union here:

```
select t1.id, t1.document1_id as doc_id, t2.document_title, t2.document_description, t3.document_filename 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.document_id=t1.document1_id
LEFT JOIN table2 t3 ON t3.document_id=t1.document1_id
UNION
select t1.id, t1.document2_id as doc_id, t2.document_title, t2.document_description, t3.document_filename 
FROM table1 t1
LEFT JOIN table2 t2 ON t2.document_id=t1.document2_id
LEFT JOIN table2 t3 ON t3.document_id=t1.document2_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what else you have in table1, having two separate document IDs in the same row may not be a good idea. But what you could try is a union subquery:

```
SELECT table2.*, table3.*
  FROM (
    SELECT document_id1 AS document_id
      FROM table1
      WHERE id = ?
    UNION ALL
    SELECT document_id2 AS document_id
      FROM table1
      WHERE id = ?
  ) table1a
  INNER JOIN table2 ON table1a.document_id = table2.document_id
  INNER JOIN table3 on table1a.document_id = table3.document_id
```

Don't use `*` in production code of course.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this seems like it would do what you want without any nested selects.

```
SELECT Table1.id, Table1.document1_id, Table1.document2_id,
       Table2.document_title, Table2.document_description,
       Table3.document_filename
FROM Table1 JOIN Table2 ON Table2.document_id = Table1.document1_id OR
                           Table2.document_id = Table1.document2_id
            JOIN Table3 ON Table3.document_id = Table2.document_id
WHERE Table1.id = ?
```